# error on dynamic combobox asp.net when binding data

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, combobox

related to this post [Fill ComboBox Dynamically in asp.net.. help required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530677/fill-combobox-dynamically-in-asp-net-help-required) I follow the code from that post, but when I tried to binding data, I've got error

> Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Step" SortExpression="ID"><InsertItemTemplate>
        :&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" AutoPostBack="true"
            DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="code" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ID") %>' AppendDataBoundItems="true"
            Width="300px" Height="25px">
            <asp:ListItem Value=" " Text="---Select---"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="KKL Step" SortExpression="ID">
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        :&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList6s" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5"
            DataTextField="KKL_Name" DataValueField="ID" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
            SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ID") %>' Width="300px" Height="25px">
            <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="---Select---"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource5" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Koneksi %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [TBL_KKL] WHERE (code=@code)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:controlParameter controlID="DropDownList2"
            propertyname="SelectedValue" Name="code" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its better to bind values to dropdown lists using C# code. Its ease and clear.
So in the **RowDataBound** event of the gridview you can write a code similar to this according to your syntax.

```
protected void dtgItemDetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
         DataTable dtDetails = GetDetailsFromDataBase();

         DropDownList DropDownList2= (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList2");
         DropDownList2.DataTextField = "Name";
         DropDownList2.DataValueField = "ID";
         DropDownList2.DataSource = dtDetails ;
         DropDownList2.DataBind();
     }
}
```

This is a sample code and you should change it according to yours.
Instead of DB calls inside the RowDataBound method, you can have Sessions or ViewStates with already filled with your data.

Comment: it still wont work, i dont know why, but when i remove selectedValue data bind on dropdownlist6s, the combobox works but its the same thing if it cant save the value, but when im trying to binding data, ive gott that errors :(

Comment: Add above DropDown filling method for your all dropdown lists in the gridview.